# How to use Rx to monitor a file for changes in Android?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I would like to use Rx to monitor a saved text file for changes in Android.
Is there any equivalent of [rxjava-file](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-file) for Android ? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't find anything prepackaged, but it should be easy enough to wrap FileObserver in Observable. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give a try and then I will post my code.